# Quartz JobStore with Spring Framework

Tags: java, spring, quartz-scheduler

I am implementing Quartz Job Store on Oracle DB using Spring Framework. My ApplicationContext.xml is below

```
<bean id="driverJob" class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.JobDetailBean">
    <property name="jobClass" value="BatchFileCollector" />
</bean>

<bean id="ranchTrigger" class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SimpleTriggerBean">
    <property name="jobDetail" ref="driverJob" />
    <property name="startDelay" value="2000" />
    <property name="repeatInterval" value="10000" />
</bean>

<bean class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SchedulerFactoryBean">
    <property name="triggers">
        <list>
            <ref bean="ranchTrigger" />
        </list>
    </property>
    <property name="dataSource">
        <ref bean="dataSource.TEXAN"/>
    </property>
    <property name="applicationContextSchedulerContextKey">
        <value>applicationContext</value>
    </property>
    <property name="autoStartup">
        <value>true</value>
    </property>
    <property name="configLocation" value="classpath:quartz.properties"/>
</bean>
```

This configuration gives me the below error.

```
Caused by: org.quartz.JobPersistenceException: 

Couldn't store trigger: The job (DEFAULT.driverJob) referenced by the trigger does not exist. 

[See nested exception: org.quartz.JobPersistenceException: The job (DEFAULT.driverJob) referenced by the trigger does not exist.]
```

I am using Spring Framework 2.5.6. Do I have to upgrade my Quartz version?
I cannot find the problem.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Please post the full stack trace, not just the exception text

Comment: You can go through following links http://jksnu.blogspot.com/2011/03/quartz-framework-implementation-with.html

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Your SchedulerFactoryBean needs to have the "driverJob" registered, too. Along with your triggers, add a list of jobDetails.

```
<bean id="job.statistics.DailyQPSValidationJobTrigger" class="org.quartz.CronTrigger">
    <property name="name" value="DailyQPSValidationTrigger" />
    <property name="jobName" value="DailyQPSValidation" />
    <property name="jobGroup" value="Statistics" />
    <property name="volatility" value="false" />
    <!-- Each day, 4 o'clock AM -->
    <property name="cronExpression" value="0 0 4 * * ?" />
</bean>

<!-- Scheduler -->

<bean id="job.SchedulerProperties" class="somecompany.someproduct.util.spring.PropertiesFactoryBean"
    scope="singleton">
    <property name="source">
        <props>
            <prop key="org.quartz.scheduler.instanceId">AUTO</prop>
            <prop key="org.quartz.scheduler.instanceName">JobCluster</prop>
            <prop key="org.quartz.jobStore.class">org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreTX</prop>
            <prop key="org.quartz.jobStore.driverDelegateClass">org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.StdJDBCDelegate</prop>
            <prop key="org.quartz.jobStore.isClustered">true</prop>
            <prop key="org.quartz.jobStore.useProperties">false</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="job.Scheduler" class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SchedulerFactoryBean" scope="singleton"
    lazy-init="false">
    <property name="startupDelay" value="30" />
    <property name="waitForJobsToCompleteOnShutdown" value="true" />
    <property name="dataSource" ref="jdbc.DataSource" />
    <property name="quartzProperties" ref="job.SchedulerProperties" />
    <property name="jobDetails">
        <list>
            <ref bean="job.statistics.DailyQPSValidationJobDetail" />
        </list>
    </property>
    <property name="triggers">
        <list>
            <ref bean="job.statistics.DailyQPSValidationJobTrigger" />
        </list>
    </property>
    <property name="schedulerListeners">
        <list>
            <bean class="somecompany.someproduct.job.SchedulerErrorListener">
                <property name="monitoringService" ref="monitoring.MonitoringService" />
            </bean>
        </list>
    </property>
    <property name="globalJobListeners">
        <list>
            <bean class="somecompany.someproduct.job.JobErrorListener">
                <property name="name" value="JobErrorListener" />
                <property name="monitoringService" ref="monitoring.MonitoringService" />
            </bean>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Comment: I think there is no need to add driverJob to SchedulerFactoryBean because ranchTrigger Bean includes driverJob. Could you please send a sample configuration for Quartz JobStore using Spring Framework?

Comment: Do you think or haven you tried? Just add the job to the scheduler. And check your jobClass "BatchFileCollector". Is it really part of the Default package? And you should give the Job a name and a group and reference it from the Trigger... I'll append an example.

Answer (score 2):

I have the same problem with Quartz 1.5.2 and Spring 3.0.4. The problem is that the JobStoreSupport class tries to store a cron trigger with a foreign key to the job (tries to load the job from the db), which is not persisted yet.

Same problem with quartz 1.6.1, 1.7.2 versions.

```
<bean id="quartzScheduler" class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SchedulerFactoryBean"
      depends-on="quartzDatabaseCreator">
    <property name="autoStartup">
        <value>true</value>
    </property>
    <property name="dataSource">
        <ref bean="dataSource"/>
    </property>
    <property name="quartzProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="org.quartz.jobStore.selectWithLockSQL">SELECT * FROM {0}LOCKS UPDLOCK WHERE LOCK_NAME = ?
            </prop>
            <prop key="org.quartz.jobStore.driverDelegateClass">org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.${qrtz.delegateClass}
            </prop>
        </props>
    </property>
    <property name="triggers">
        <list>
            <ref bean="cronTrigger"/>
        </list>
    </property>
    <property name="schedulerContextAsMap">
        <map>
            <entry key="sygnoServerHelper"><ref bean="sygnoServerHelper"/></entry>
            <entry key="requestDAO"><ref bean="requestDAO"/></entry>
            <entry key="alairoCache"><ref bean="alairoCache"/></entry>
        </map>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="cronTrigger" class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.CronTriggerBean">
    <property name="jobDetail" ref="checkGracePeriodJob" />
    <!--                                 # s m h dom mon dow [y]  -->
    <property name="cronExpression" value="0 0/5 * * * ?" />
</bean>

<bean id="checkGracePeriodJob" class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.JobDetailBean">
    <property name="jobClass" value="com.synergon.sygnoserver.CheckGracePeriodJob"/>
 </bean>
```

Comment: And what is a solution to this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this will work, but you could try using:

```
   <bean id="driverJob" .../>
```

instead of:

```
   <bean name="driverJob" .../>
```

Comment: It doesn't work. BatchFileCollector class extends org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.QuartzJobBean.