# Quartz + Spring : Configure jobs to run on specific time using JobStore

Tags: java, spring, quartz-scheduler

I'm trying out Quartz scheduler and managed to get it to work with Spring using Maven.

What I need to do is configure Quartz to store the jobs so that for a scheduled time it may execute the job. As far as I know there are two types of triggers in Quartz, Simple and Cron. And I also found out that there is something called JobStore in Quartz. I got it configured to some extent.

Could someone please give me a good reference/references on how to setup Quartz, JobStore? Big help, thank you.

Comment: I have written a blog post on Quartz that uses a REST API to schedule jobs and uses liquibase to manage database migrations.    http://juliuskrah.com/tutorial/2017/10/06/persisting-dynamic-jobs-with-quartz-and-spring/

Answer (score 1):

You can have a look at these links
[Quartz JobStore with Spring Framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1187882/quartz-jobstore-with-spring-framework)
http://trimplement.com/using-spring-and-quartz-with-jobstore-properties/

If you still cant figure it out then let me know

Comment: Thanks. I added in a context file the necessary beans for job, triggers and schedule. I've created a database using the scripts that come with the Quartz distribution as well.

Set necessary properties in the ScheduleFactory bean in the context file. It throws an exception saying

org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.LockException:
Failure obtaining db row lock: You have an error in your SQL syntax;
check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '(UPDLOCK,ROWLOCK) WHERE SCHED_NAME = 'org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.Sche' at line 1

Comment: This error means "org.quartz.jobStore.driverDelegateClass=org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.StdJDBCDelegate",  you may configure with some other database Delegate, for example MSSQL

Answer (score 0):

Just to give you another option, have you try task scheduling of Spring?. Nowadays I change all my old Quartz jobs for this and is easier to configure and you can use the annotations.

http://spring.io/blog/2010/01/05/task-scheduling-simplifications-in-spring-3-0/

Comment: Thank you @paul, will check about that.

Answer (score 0):

You will usually create a `Scheduler` from a factory class. Quartz can be setup in several ways.

1. By using the `org.quartz.impl.StdSchedulerFactory.getDefaultScheduler()`. This will load the `quartz.properties` file in the Quartz distribution if you have not provided your own.
2. By specifying your configuration as Key-Value pairs in a `quartz.properties` file and loading it in `org.quartz.impl.StdSchedulerFactory(java.lang.String fileName).getScheduler()`.
3. By specifying your configuration  in a `java.util.Properties` as Key-Value pairs and loading it in `org.quartz.impl.StdSchedulerFactory(java.util.Properties props).getScheduler()`.
4. By using the `spring-context-support` jar from the Spring Framework and using a higher level abstraction such as `org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SchedulerFactoryBean`.
5. etc.

Quartz will start triggering jobs only when the `org.quartz.Scheduler#start()` has been invoked. Until this method is called the `Scheduler` will be in Standby mode.
The Scheduler can be destroyed to release threads by calling `org.quartz.Scheduler#shutdown()`.

## Example of Bootstrapping Quartz with Spring

```
@org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration
public class QuartzExample {
    ...
    @org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean
    public org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SchedulerFactoryBean schedulerFactory() {
        org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SchedulerFactoryBean factoryBean = new org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SchedulerFactoryBean();
        return factoryBean;
    }
}
```

The bean definition above is enough to perform the following configuration:-

1. JobFactory - The default is Spring’s `org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.AdaptableJobFactory`, which supports `java.lang.Runnable` objects as well as standard Quartz `org.quartz.Job` instances.
2. ThreadPool - Default is a Quartz `org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool` with a pool size of 10. This is configured through the corresponding Quartz properties.
3. SchedulerFactory - The default used here is the `org.quartz.impl.StdSchedulerFactory`, reading in the standard `quartz.properties` from `quartz.jar`.
4. JobStore - The default used is `org.quartz.simpl.RAMJobStore` which does not support persistence and is not clustered.
5. Life-Cycle - The `org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SchedulerFactoryBean` implements `org.springframework.context.SmartLifecycle` and `org.springframework.beans.factory.DisposableBean` which means the life-cycle of the scheduler is managed by the Spring container. The `org.quartz.Scheduler#start()` is called in the `start()` implementation of `SmartLifecycle` after initialization and the `org.quartz.Scheduler#shutdown()` is called in the `destroy()` implementation of `DisposableBean` at application teardown.
   You can override the startup behaviour by setting `org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SchedulerFactoryBean().setAutoStartup(false)`. With this setting you have to manually start the scheduler.

All these default settings can be overridden by the calling the various setter methods on `org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SchedulerFactoryBean`.

I have provided a full working example on [Github](https://github.com/juliuskrah/quartz-manager/tree/v1.x). If you are interested in an example that saves the jobs in a database checkout the [HSQLDB](https://github.com/juliuskrah/quartz-manager/tree/v2.x) branch of the same repository.